# Robot Framework error : InvalidHeader: Invalid return character or leading space in header: Cookie

Tags: robotframework

Set Cookie

```
open Browser    ${rbcurl}    ${browser}    options=add_argument("--incognito")    options=add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

Maximize Browser Window
sleep   15
input text    xpath://*[@id="i0116"]       *******
sleep    5
click element    xpath://*[@id="idSIButton9"]
sleep   10
input text    xpath://*[@id="i0118"]       ******
sleep   10
click element   xpath://*[@id="idSIButton9"]
sleep   10
#Get Cookies
${cookies}=    Get Cookies
${str}=       String.Split String    ${cookies}    ;
Log       ${str}
Log       ${str}[0]
Log       ${str}[1]
Log       ${str}[2]
Log       ${str}[3]
Log       ${str}[4]
${final_cookie}=  set variable    ${str}[1]
#Api for waldo
[Arguments]  ${final_cookie}
${params} =  Create Dictionary  fields=jive
${headers} =  Create Dictionary  Cookie=${final_cookie}
${response} =  get request  WaldoJive  /api/core/v3/people/@me?  headers=${headers}  params=${params}
#https://one.rbc.com/api/core/v3/people/@me?fields=jive  ${headers}  ${params}
#Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${response}
Set Test Variable  ${response}  ${response}
set global variable  ${RESPONSE_DATA}  ${response.json()}
```

Can someone please help here why i am getting below error
InvalidHeader: Invalid return character or leading space in header: Cookie

**If it is expected from code then how can i overcome to this**

**Final Api request**

```
GET Request using : uri=/api/core/v3/people/@me?, params={'fields': 'jive'}, allow_redirects=True, timeout=None
```

headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.23.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': ' jive.security.context=eyJraWQiOiI4M2ZjZjc5OC1mNzFhLTQ1NWMtOGU3Ni01MDIxODQ1YWVlYzciLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJKaXZlIiwiYXVkIjoiYWNjZXNzX3Rva2VuIiwiaWF0IjoxNjYwOTA2NTc0LCJqdGkiOiJzMzJaX004QVlkT1ZGNk1KUlB5VmN3IiwibmJmIjoxNjYwOTA2NDU0LCJzdWIiOiJqaXZlLWF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uIiwidGVuYW50SWQiOiIyY2Y1MWIwNy05NDNmLTQzOWEtODA3MC0yMDExNGE4NDAzMjYiLCJ1c2VySWQiOjE3NDQzNCwidHlwIjoiSldUIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjYwOTA2NTc0LCJleHAiOjE2NjEwNzkzNzQsImlhdFRUTCI6MTY2MTA3OTM3NH0.qHbh7KLC5IewS8eZcAiEdKzxMyUVVz_TBfiDIJq7MoJo3o8ZzU0toCTAwdOPEXwI_uVC70Fh_ndKVMrC1b4EFCzdax5macsoSQt5tyHFQy35OLgMV8Im2l9EPXGbHRbe_O-xHqOGbrsaoVvc06ZaTFPO80eYKwinR4WQihd-JpSwA211RUe7Yw7MuKIHLPVi2-lrrrSSKYcvKtOv-74SP0onAaegPn5HLTyp8jMHFQ7g04KzCD-5M9JJIorz20zOoSFLJNnEj4IqUW8tRcIQoLqLLRsg8vefV0baKQ3KTQXM7IBX_88NXZxs0o95Q5HGdo0oFK7pBZWx6jEOtM1piQ'}

data=None
json=None

Comment: Can you cut the code to just the lines reproducing the error; and pinpoint which line is throwing it. I guess it's the `Get Cookies` one, but that is just sa guess.

Comment: ${str}=       String.Split String    ${cookies}    ; this line was throwing the error due to ; (semicolon) . When I removed it error is resolved . Thanks Todor @TodorMinakov

Comment: Would you take the time to edit your question?